# Navigation bar pushed upwards when keyboard shows up SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am having trouble why my navigation bar pushed upward when keyboard shows up (refer to the first image). Unlike to the second image (iMessage screenshot), the navigation bar doesn't pushed upwards when keyboard.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConversationView: View {
    @State var message : String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Divider()
            TextField("Write a message here .....",text: $message)
                .padding(.all,10)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 13)
                        .stroke(Constants.black_100, lineWidth: 1)
                )
        }
        .padding(.all,5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer because this doesnt keep the navBar in place, but maybe you are intersted in something like this:
`navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = true`

Comment: Thank you for the response. But how do apple did on iMessage app? @stackich